# Callback from IPostprocessBuildWithReport returns Unknown (while it should return succeed)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am working on some logic that needs to execute after a build has been succeeded, but so far I only get ***BuildResult.Unknown*** back. It does get triggered after the Player has been build successfully. The following code is almost the same from the Scripting Reference. I would expect a failed, succeeded or canceled build after a Postprocessor, but not an "unknown" result. I am using Unity 2018.2.8f1 (latest) on OSX.

```
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEditor.Build;
using UnityEditor.Build.Reporting;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor.Callbacks;

class MyBuildPostprocessor : IPostprocessBuildWithReport
{
  public int callbackOrder { get { return 0; } }

  public void OnPostprocessBuild(BuildReport report)
  {
    Debug.Log("Build Status : " + report.summary.result);
  }
}
```

Comment: What platform did you build to that reports "unknown"? What's your Unity version?

Comment: Desktop, OSXStandalone - Unity 2018.2.8f1

Comment: Looks like a bug to me. You should for a bug report and hope for them to fix it